# Is it possible to sort search result using UTC meta tag in GSA

Tags: google-search-appliance

We have the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="date" value="2017-08-25T15:59:53.484Z"/>
```

Is it possible to sort search result using this tag? Or [only the following](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/admin_console_help/crawl_sort.html#ValidFormats) list of formats is supported?

According to this [link](https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/current/admin_console_help/crawl_sort.html#def_date_format) it is possible to define custom date format. Is it possible to configure document dates using UTC format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the supported formats list **%Y%m%d%H** seems to be the one you should use since it results in purely numerical value that should be easy to sort.